# Handling the second mousedown event on a double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using plain Javascript or JQuery, what would be the best way to handle the *second `mousedown` event* during a double click?

I want to run an action before the "`dblclick`" event is fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `mousedown` event listener like this in plain js that will trigger before your dblclick event:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (event.detail == 2) {
    // do stuff here
  }
}, false);
```

And here's a snippet to demonstrate:

```js
$(document).on('dblclick', function() {
  console.log('dblclick event');
});
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (event.detail == 2) {
    console.log('second mouse click event before dblclick');
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Do some double clicks...
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are still people using IE